# SQLAlchemy Ideal Design for Committing

Tags: sqlalchemy, commit

I have a Pylons back-end running on SQLAlchemy. I have a script that reads a tree of XML files from an HTTP server (it downloads an xml X, and then downloads that X's children, and then iterates the children, and so forth in recursion). Each xml file represents an SQLAlchemy model.

The problem is that I have thousands of these xml's (sometimes 5000, sometimes 26000). I was able to optimize the download process with HTTP pooling, but I cannot seem to think of the best approach as to committing the models to the DB. Every time an xml file is downloaded, I create an orm object for it and add it to my session.

Problem 1: some xml's will exists multiple times in the tree so I am checking that there is no duplicate insertion. Is the check in my code optimal or should I keep an indexed collection on the side and use it to check for duplicates?

Problem 2: my autocommit is set to False because I don't want to commit on every add (not because its bad design, but because of performance). But I also don't want to iterate the entire tree of thousands of categories without committing at all. Therefor, I created a constant number upon which my code commits the data. Is this a good approach? What would be a good number for that? It might be important to mention that I do not know in advance how many xml's I am looking at.

Here is what my pseudo-code looks like now (ignore syntax errors):

```
count = 0
COMMIT_EVERY = 50

def recursion(parent):
    global count, COMMIT_EVERY
    pool = get_http_connection_pool(...)
    sub_xmls = get_sub_xmls(pool, parent)

    if sub_xmls == None:
        return

    for sub_xml in sub_xmls:
        orm_obj = MyObj(sub_xml)

        duplicate = Session.query(MyObj).filter(MyObj.id == orm_obj.id).first()
        if not duplicate:
            Session.add(orm_obj)
            count = count + 1
            if count % COMMIT_EVERY == 0:
                Session.commit()            
            recursion(orm_obj.id)

recursion(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add a `UniqueConstraint` to your model table and forget about querying for duplicates then simply:

```
try:
    Session.add(orm_obj)
except IntegrityError:
    log.warn("A duplicate found") #or just pass
```

A good `COMMIT_EVERY` value is up to you, test different values, profile performances, value risks, I think no one can tell you a number with so a few informations.

P.S.:

```
if sub_xmls is None:
    return
```

**EDIT:**

Sqlalchemy can be configured to make inserts **on commit**, that's why you get `IntegrityError` only on commit, or simply every time you make a add, read documentation or ask on [SA group](http://groups.google.com/group/sqlalchemy), I can't help you that much.

Or use sql directly and also gain in performances: for example this will raise exception for each duplicate (`MySQL` syntax, check your own DBRMS):

```
conn = Session.connection()
try:
    curs = conn.execute("INSERT INTO table (id, value) VALUES (%s, %s)", (id, value))
except IntegrityError:
    log.warn("A duplicate found: id=%s" % id)
finally:
    #remember to close cursor
    curs.close()
```

Comment: That id is a primary key, and therefor is unique. However, I saw that when I add duplicate values, no exceptions is thrown UNTIL I call commit. So Session.add(Obj(id=1)), Session.add(Obj(id=1)) wont throw and exception, but then calling Session.commit() will. Taking into account my flow, this sucks... Is there a way around this? And is the "commit every" a good approach in general? Thanks so much!

Comment: @Raiders: updated answer. In my opinion the _commit every_ is reasonable.

Comment: @Raiders: I see [here](http://groups.google.com/group/sqlalchemy/browse_thread/thread/643e5135fb264265) Michael Bayer advises against `try except` to find duplicates using `SA` but I use it extensively like in my last example and have no problems and also performances are good also with big amounts of data.